# Do x86 and other architectures have a fused shift and add?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, instructions

A number of architectures support fused multiply and add such as x86 with `pmaddwd` (and its SSE extensions), but I am unaware of any x86 fused *shift* and add which is effectively equivalent to FMA. This question is predominantly about x86, but knowing about other architectures would be useful as well.

Is there a way to effectively get a fused shift and add based on CPU-family-specific IPC perhaps?

Both `shx/shr/shl` and `add/adc/sub` are listed as one cycle with reciprocal throughput of 0.25 according to AMD's Family 17h Instruction Latencies version 1.00 spreadsheet.

But for a use-case that matches a fused shift/add, they need to operate on the same input and are dependent on each other so they necessarily will execute sequentially in two cycles. Using FMA instead would be three cycles regardless (with worse throughput).

Comment: There is `lea` if you want to shift left by 1, 2 or 3, but otherwise I don't know of any.

Comment: ARM and ARM64 do have this; there is a form of the `add` instruction that applies a shift to one operand before adding.  ARM32 allows either a constant or variable shift; ARM64 has constant shift only.

Comment: But whether the execution is actually "fused" is up to the specific microarchitecture.  On my Cortex-A72 it appears that the shifted version of `add` takes an extra uop, so the only benefit over separate shift and add instructions is to reduce code size and avoid the need for a scratch register.

Comment: What if you want to do something like `x << (-popcnt(x) - 1)`?

Comment: @AMDG That is just a *simple shift* with variable shift count: `x << (~popcnt(x))`. Where does shift-add come into play? Did you mean to place parentheses differently? FWIW, various NVIDIA GPU architectures have an `ISCADD` instruction which is left-shift & add (presumably the name is derived from **i**nteger **sc**ale & **add**).

Comment: Note "fused shift-add" suggests to me `a + (b << c)`, not `(a+b) << c` or `a << (b + c)`, and that's the analogy of what FMA does.  The other versions don't seem likely to exist as instructions.

Comment: Historical perspective: The PA-RISC architecture had `SH1ADD`, `SH2ADD`, and `SH3ADD` instructions, so fused shift-add `(a << s) + b` with `s` limited to a fixed value of 1, 2, or 3. As with x86 `LEA` this was presumably primarily intended for address arithmetic.

Comment: @njuffa I mean fused shift-add as a direct analog to FMA: given `a * b + a * c` where `a` is a perfect power of two and `b` and `c` are signed or unsigned integers, compute `(b << a) + (c << a)`.

Comment: @AMDG As Nate Eldredge already pointed out, in established terminology fused left-shift-add is `(a << b) + c`; compare analogous `fma (a, b, c) = a * b + c`.  Given that, how does this operation fit with the given example `x << (-popcnt(x) - 1) == x << (~popcnt(x))`, which is just a simple shift?

Comment: @njuffa Suppose we want to compute a rational divide or a reciprocal using a linear approximation, $f(x) = (3 - x 2^(-floor(log_2(x)))) 2^(-floor(log_2(x)))$, then apply iterations of the form $f(x) f(x f(x))$ for rapid convergence (better than Newton-Raphson in certain cases). On its own, f(x) can be computed in 4 cycles. Having fused shift-add would make it 3 cycles for f(x) alone making subsequent iterations faster.

Comment: `a*b + a*c` is what `pmaddwd` does, you're right, but the term "fused multiply-add" more commonly means `a+(b*c)`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation

Comment: @NateEldredge My apologies for the mixup and any confusion!

Comment: Correction: the outermost coefficient in f(x) should be $2^(-1 - floor(log_2(x)))$.

Comment: Arm Neon has fused `a + (b >> imm)`.